# how to get input class value by javascript

Tags: javascript

I know jQuery is easy to get the value but how can i use **Javascript only** to get the value?

[This is what I did](http://jsfiddle.net/2vRCU/)

```
<input type="text" class="num" /> <a href="#" onclick="alert(document.getElementsByClassName('num').value);"> click </a>
```

​

thanks for help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements. You're looking for the first element in that array:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('num')[0].value;
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2vRCU/1/**

Answer (score 2):

i think the most common way to do that is give the element a "id" .... at least it's what i did when i was using javascript in old days before jQuery and all other JS frameworks.

```
<input id='mytext' type="text" class="num" />
```

and use this to capture:

```
document.getElementById('mytext');
```

so it will be:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('mytext').value);"> click </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('mytext').className;
```